# What is the command to get the wifi name of a BSSID device in Kali Linux?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, mac-address

I only have the BSSID of the specific target device I want to connect to.

How can I determine the actual Wi-Fi network name that the device is connected to?

I'm using kali linux, and I used `crunch 8 14 | aircrack-ng -a2 -b [target device BSSID] -w [file saved using airodump-ng]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the **Wi-Fi (SSID)** to a specific **BSSID**, you can use the `wash` command.

`wash` is a utility provided by the `reaver package`.

Install the reaver package:

`apt-get install reaver`

Use the following command to run `wash` and scan for nearby access points, replace `[INTERFACE]` with the name of your wireless network interface:

`wash -i [INTERFACE]`

`wash` will display a list of access points along with their `BSSID`.

**Source:**

[Wash Description](https://en.kali.tools/?p=341)

[reaver | wash Usage Example](https://www.kali.org/tools/reaver/)

[How to use the wash command to find WPS enabled routers with Backtrack 5 or Kali Linux](https://www.wirelesshack.org/how-to-use-the-wash-command-to-find-wps-enabled-routers-with-backtrack-5-or-kali-linux.html)